# Password Bishop Goodness

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, palindrome

*Derived from [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/179836/43319), now deleted, post.*

Given a string, answer (truthy/falsy or two consistent values) if it constitutes a good Bishop password, which is when all the following conditions are met:

1. it has at least 10 characters
2. it has at least 3 digits (`[0-9]`)
3. it is not a palindrome (identical to itself when reversed)

You get 0 bytes bonus if your code is a good Bishop password.

**Warning:** Do *not* use Bishop goodness as a measure of actual password strength!

### Examples

#### Good Bishop passwords

`PPCG123GCPP`
`PPCG123PPCG`
`PPCG123gcpp`
`0123456789`
`Tr0ub4dor&3`

#### Not Good Bishop passwords

`PPCG123` (too short)
`correct horse battery staple` (not enough digits)
`PPCG121GCPP` (palindrome)
 (too short and not enough digits)
`abc121cba` (too short and palindrome)
`aaaaaaaaaaaa` (palindrome and not enough digits)
`abc99cba` (everything wrong)

Comment: @KrystosTheOverlord The term is defined in this challenge itself. ;-P

Comment: Aw, I was expecting some chess logic password rules…

Comment: I read through all the answers and not one claimed the bonus.

Comment: "You get 0 bytes bonus if your code is a good Bishop password" — this confuses me. Is it a real bonus or not?

Comment: @JDL you really get to substract 0 bytes from your score if you qualify for this very real bonus! What are you waiting for?

Comment: surely it would be far harder to write a legitimate solution that *wasn't* a good Bishop password (though I suppose you could add a comment at the end to make it into a palindrome)

Comment: One of your criteria is actually the reverse of what Bishop (2013) proposed. He proposed that passwords must be 10 characters or less, not more.

Comment: Are you telling me [correct horse battery staple](https://xkcd.com/936/) is not a good password? /s

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>61</s> <s>59</s> <s>54</s> 51 bytes

```python
lambda s:sum(map(str.isdigit,s))>2<s[:9]<s<>s[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY@9bsJAEIR7nuIqzpYIwoYQbDkUoXAXuaBLKO7H4JMwe9pdhHh645AUB6Rgmx19M1rN@jM3cEi77ft3t1ettkpQTsc2apWPiHHsyLqd4xHF8TIt6CvPNgUVy17kL8mm8@gOLEsAKz4cNeCFV0QnQEu5HAyutthGsqpWZZJOy1VVyfgB/6x/8M54H@JJz2av87dFFtI1To56ZgGH0x7/8j9XfgKLp8uFRw0g1oZFA0i10Iq5xrMgVn5fPzZN7v8KtdKmTxitbmAwd@Esu2a7Cw)

<sub>-5 bytes, thanks to Erik the Outgolfer</sub>

<sub>-3 bytes, thanks to xnor</sub>

Comment: [Choo choo!](https://tio.run/##jc89T8NADAbgvb/iWLhEAtSk5SNRykCHbChDN2C4rzYnJfHJdoX660MoDNeWgVt8evzKssOBWxjycbt6HzvVa6sElbTvk16FhBjvPFm/83xDafqcV0XVuSGhtKKrFb2V5W32MQb0A8sawIoXTy0EERTRJ6ClUs5mx7bYJrJp1nWWL@p108j0gr/LH7wzIcQ8n2x5//D4VMS6wfleLy3g9WLiH//tyldg8e/l4qEGEJ1h0QKSE1oxOzwIYhU6d7lpdn5X/FfaTAmj1QlG7yxcFMfs@AU)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Thanks:)

Comment: You can do the length check as `s[:9]<s`, which combines well with the non-palindrome check: `s[:9]<s!=s[::-1]`

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>17</s> 14 bytes

```
Ê¨A&U¦Ô&3§Uè\d
```

*-3 bytes rearranged by @Shaggy*

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=yqgxMCZVptQmM6dV6Fxk&input=WwpUUlVFCiLKqDEwJlWm1CYzp1XoXGQiCiJQUENHMTIzR0NQUCIKIlBQQ0cxMjNQUENHIgoiUFBDRzEyM2djcHAiCiIwMTIzNDU2Nzg5IgoiVHIwdWI0ZG9yJjMiCkZBTFNFCiJQUENHMTIzIgoiY29ycmVjdCBob3JzZSBiYXR0ZXJ5IHN0YXBsZSIKIlBQQ0cxMjFHQ1BQIgoiYWJjMTIxY2JhIgoiYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhIgoiYWJjOTljYmEiCl0gLW1S)

---

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt),  15 bytes (0 Bytes Bonus :v)

```
Ê¨10&U¦Ô&3§Uè\d
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=yqgxMCZVptQmM6dV6Fxk&input=WwpUUlVFCiLKqDEwJlWm1CYzp1XoXGQiCiJQUENHMTIzR0NQUCIKIlBQQ0cxMjNQUENHIgoiUFBDRzEyM2djcHAiCiIwMTIzNDU2Nzg5IgoiVHIwdWI0ZG9yJjMiCkZBTFNFCiJQUENHMTIzIgoiY29ycmVjdCBob3JzZSBiYXR0ZXJ5IHN0YXBsZSIKIlBQQ0cxMjFHQ1BQIgoiYWJjMTIxY2JhIgoiYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhIgoiYWJjOTljYmEiCl0gLW1S)

Comment: Dang! Should've checked the solutions before starting my own! [14 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=yqhBJlWm1CYzp1XoXGQ=&input=WwpUUlVFCiJQUENHMTIzR0NQUCIKIlBQQ0cxMjNQUENHIgoiUFBDRzEyM2djcHAiCiIwMTIzNDU2Nzg5IgoiVHIwdWI0ZG9yJjMiCkZBTFNFCiJQUENHMTIzIgoiY29ycmVjdCBob3JzZSBiYXR0ZXJ5IHN0YXBsZSIKIlBQQ0cxMjFHQ1BQIgoiYWJjMTIxY2JhIgoiYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhIgoiYWJjOTljYmEiCl0gLW1S)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
gT@Iþg3@IÂÊP
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/PcTB8/C@dGMg2XS4K@D//4AAZ3dDI2N354AAAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/9BCHysP70o2BZNPhroD/Ov@jlQICnN0NjYzdnQMClHQUYFwQhcRNTy4oAHENgGwTUzNzC0sQL6TIoDTJJCW/SM0YxEVSD2Im5xcVpSaXKGTkFxWnKiQllpSkFlUqFJckFuSkIpQawixOTEoG8pKTEsEcJACVtLSEyikoxQIA).

**Explanation:**

```python
g      # Get the length of the (implicit) input
 T@    # Check if this length >= 10
Iþ     # Get the input and only leave the digits
  g    # Then get the length (amount of digits)
   3@  # And check if the amount of digits >= 3
IÂ     # Get the input and the input reversed
  Ê    # Check if they are not equal (so not a palindrome)
P      # Check if all three above are truthy (and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>80</s> <s>70</s> <s>62</s> <s>64</s> 63 bytes

```r
any(rev(U<-utf8ToInt(scan(,'')))<U)&sum(U>47&U<58)>2&sum(U|1)>9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BjoIwEIbvPsXETaBNViKKCgnLxYPZGwd5gFJaJGFbMi2rxvXZWZRdxR6m@b75JzPYvcERWQOGM0UoVAoYyFZxW2kFUiMIZiqBYIWxlSon8uO/S070cpuKZw/jeR69nK4dU2eC4ptk8ay1MtzrT2XJfcO761JK44w6pv0iWRJsnCxehTRZDOLHp0nUXSeSTA@irvVRY134i@WU9spN0@2uh902Td2xuH0vouRNM4h5T8FqvQmjgfc4b/Og0OgsXyYG4BpRcAsHjUZAzqwVeAZjWVOLcdx/njBUlvPe8pz94eg9AlH07PfxQpZ37n4B)

From digEmAll, and some rearranging too

```r
sum((s<-el(strsplit(scan(,''),"")))%in%0:9)>2&!all(s==rev(s))&s[10]>''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpLCoAgEADQsySoM2CQtirKi0QLKaFg@uD0Ob711i/lzPcGwF0ZCfhKfNJ6AU9hB6M1GiEQUa67rNoGvVNFoP/1fYoPMKLiwVaj1zqLJRId75Fotq4W@QM)

Pretty straightforward, no real amazing tricks here. After user inputs string:

- Separates and searches the string for more than 2 numbers. (3 or more digits)
- Checks if not all elements are equal to the reversed version of the string (palindrome)
- Checks that length is greater than 9 (10 or more characters)

Comment: I think you can replace `!all(s==rev(s))` with `any(s!=rev(s))` which will save one byte. I feel like the length check can be reduced too, but not sure how (either `nchar` or some kind of `sum(x|1)` hack)

Comment: actually, I think `any(s>rev(s))` will work --- if a character is less than its palindromic counterpart, then at the other end of the password the converse will be true. That saves another byte.

Comment: can use `grepl()` instead of `grep()|1` to save 1 byte, or better use `()%in%0:9`

Comment: instead of `length(s)>9` you could use `s[10]>''`. it will return `TRUE` if there is a tenth element, and `NA` (which is falsy) if there is no tenth element.

Comment: [62 bytes using utf8ToInt](https://tio.run/##VY7JbsIwEEDvfMWISokttREpARKxXDig3nIgH@AYGyKldjR2WET59tQQljCHGb03iwabDzggq8BwpgiFQgEDWStuC61AagTBTCEQrDC2UNuenD@65EjP163Z19MEQUDPx0uTzWsr47X@UZbcDn/6PqVTpk4kW6DYk4xSz9S/jqKJl81G8R3/QrpImktPkv5OlKU@aCw34fewT53y03S5crBapqnfFdfyJra8qloxcBSNxpM4aXmNgzqPNhq94dtGC1wjCm5hp9EIyJm1Ak9gLKtK0R0PXy@0meXcWZ6zO3biOZAkt37zDw "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @digEmAll your example returns true when there is only one number, you will need to include a `>2`

Comment: @AaronHayman: you're right, I should have erroneously deleted it

Comment: [64 but correct ;)](https://tio.run/##VY5NbsIwEEb3nGJEpcSW2oifUBIVsmGBusuCHMBx7BAptaOxU0CUs6eGtBC8GOu9@WY02L3AAVkDhjNFKFQKGMhWcVtpBVIjCGYqgWCFsZUqR3L93yVHer5Ord7uJggCej5eumzdWhnt9Key5Lb41fcp/WDqRLIExTfJKPVM@@UoXHrZahHRZNaLnylN4u4ykmS8F3WtDxrrYjqbj6lTfpputg62mzT1h@L6PYmSN00vJo7Cxfsyinve4aTNw0KjN3@a6IFrRMEt7DUaATmzVuAJjGVNLYbx6eOEvrKcO8tz9oeDdw/E8aPv4oUsb9z9Ag "R – Try It Online")

Comment: You can still get it to 61 using `U[10]>0` instead of `sum(U|1)>9`, but maybe returning NA instead of FALSE is ugly

Comment: @AaronHayman: the problem is not returning NA, but that sometime it will return FALSE and sometime NA, depending on the condition not met. As far as I know one can return any thruthy/falsy value as long as they're consistent

Comment: [63 with some rearrangement](https://tio.run/##VY7BjoIwEIbvPsXETaBNViKKCgnLxYPZGwd5gFJaJGFbMi2rxvXZWZRdxR6m@b75JzPYvcERWQOGM0UoVAoYyFZxW2kFUiMIZiqBYIWxlSon8uO/S070cpuKZw/jeR69nK4dU2eC4ptk8ay1MtzrT2XJfcO761JK44w6pv0iWRJsnCxehTRZDOLHp0nUXSeSTA@irvVRY134i@WU9spN0@2uh902Td2xuH0vouRNM4h5T8FqvQmjgfc4b/Og0OgsXyYG4BpRcAsHjUZAzqwVeAZjWVOLcdx/njBUlvPe8pz94eg9AlH07PfxQpZ37n4B "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>18</s> 12 bytes

*Thanks for the tips, [Kroppeb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81957/kroppeb) and [Fatalize](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41723/fatalize)!*

```
¬↔?l>9&ịˢl>2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9CaR21T7HPsLNUe7u4@vSjHDiimFFJkUJpkkpJfpGas9B8A)

#### Explanation

The program is a single predicate, composed of two parts that are chained with `&`.

First:

```
¬       The following assertion must fail:
 ↔        The input reversed
  ?       can be unified with the input
        Also, the input's
   l    length
    >9  must be greater than 9
```

Second:

```
 ˢ     Get all outputs from applying the following to each character in the input:
ị        Convert to number
       This gives an integer for a digit character and fails for a non-digit, so
       we now have a list containing one integer for each digit in the password
  l    Its length
   >2  must be greater than 2
```

Comment: `{∋.∈Ị∧}ᶜ` can be `{∋ị}ᶜ`

Comment: Putting the "not palindrome" clause first, and changing the way to select digits, you can save 6 bytes: [`¬↔?l>9&ịˢl>2`](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9CaR21T7HPsLNUe7u4@vSjHDiimFFJkUJpkkpJfpGas9B8A)

Comment: @Kroppeb Oh, interesting! I didn't consider `ị`, but it makes sense that it would succeed iff the character is a digit. Thanks!

Comment: @Fatalize Aha--reusing the `?` like that is neat. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, <s>36, 30</s> 29 bytes

7 bytes saved thank to Adám

Index origin = 0

Prompts for input string

```
(10≤⍴v)×(3≤+/v∊∊⍕¨⍳10)>v≡⌽v←⎕
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlwPWooz3tv4ahwaPOJY96t5RpHp6uYQxka@uXPeroAqHeqYdWPOrdbGigaVf2qHPho569ZUCNQAP@A7X@T@NSJ0uzOgA)

Explanation:

```
(10≤⍴v) Length test pass 1 fail 0

(3≤+/v∊∊⍕¨⍳10) Number of digits test

>v≡⌽v Palindrome test
```

The code also qualifies for the bonus as it is a good Bishop password.

Comment: @Adám. Thanks for saving 6 bytes. On ⎕IO agreed. v≡⌽v works fine if I prepend ~. As to use of x I tend to use it when stringing together boolean tests. Same result same number of bytes.

Comment: Do you have `≢` which is `~`…`≡`? And even if you don't, you can merge `×~` into `>`

Comment: @Adám No I do not have ≢. I can merge ×~ into > for one more byte. Thanks. I am afraid my "putting game" still needs more practice ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
~Tṫ3ȧL9<Ɗ>ṚƑ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9qZWxsef//flThuaszyKdMOTzGij7huZrGkf/Dh8WS4bmY//9QUENHMTIxR0NQUA)

`[]` if not enough digits (empty list, falsy), `0` if otherwise bad (zero, falsy), `1` if good (nonzero, truthy).

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 92 bytes

```java
s->s.length()>9&s.replaceAll("\\D","").length()>2&!s.contains(new StringBuffer(s).reverse())
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##TZHLbgIhFIb3PsUpCwMZnXjrZWpq0trEVc0kdqcuGGR0LMIEGBtj3PYB@oh9kSnoTJQF8HHO4f8PbOmetrerr5IJagx80EweGwCZtFynlHGYegRIlBKcSmB4ZnUm12DI0AVODTcZS23GYAoSXqA07ZEJBZdru8FkFDVNqHku3FWvQmC0WLyjFkLkmtFr3pmQKWmdtMGSf8NF4a1IU66xIa5@z7XhmJBy6PXyIhFOr5Ldq2wFO1dcOZsvgZKL6VTp2q7lxo6p4fAMV4n58ojieDzp9vqTcRyjFtTolxtcszz32HH7wf3D41Pk6VN3imSwUrrZ93iT77dMac2ZhY1y3iGh1r3owZvOBb@mdmthmjBHLKFnuBlVMIqqGKATOXcHMDsYy3ehKmyYu36skO6BEQrqZgNH8PfzCyiQIcP1Mam@7lT@Aw)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->                        // Method with String parameter and boolean return-type
  s.length()>9             //  Check if the length of the input-String is more than 9
  &s.replaceAll("\\D","")  //  AND: remove all non-digits from the input-String
    .length()>2            //       and check if the amount of digits is more than 2
  &!s.contains(new StringBuffer(s).reverse())
                           //  AND: check if the input-String does NOT have the reversed
                           //       input-String as substring (and thus is not a palindrome)
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>60</s> <s>56</s> 46 bytes

Takes input as an array of characters. Outputs `1` for truthy and `0` for falsey.

```
s=>/(\d.*){3}/.test(s[9]&&s)&s+``!=s.reverse()
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BbsIwEETv/orAIbILOEAokEOQKtRy4RABPaWRcJwFWqXY8rqIquLbQ1zRkr3sPs1qZj7ESaA079r2jqqAahdXGM8C@lbwB/YTXgJuAS3FNMp8H5mPne22FSM3cAKDQFkl1RFVCbxUe5oSEgTeZvX6TNpJMl8MhuFiniTt7j@61cC91Nphv75Hj@PJNHK0Mf2vfFQo44c1OsuXp@X67ul@pDIGpPUOqq7h5cJaMN8eWqFLuAcM/uJFLmuSufiFxtzEKHIaIRn/FJqe49mOppzzc8YYq64)

Saved 10 bytes(!) thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld).

Answer (score 2):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 122 bytes

```
(define(d s)(let([t(string->list s)])(and(< 2(length(filter char-numeric? t)))(< 9(length t))(not(equal? t(reverse t))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY89T8QwDIb3/oqoSMgdTtwXH5UQDDfc2oENMbiJr43IpcVxke7XH05BBxtWpPjJ@0avzWjfSc5XAWNneIabFhOdwdHBRwJnUgWBBF4FkrCP3eIp@CT6/FYBRgePZq2G2EkPBx@E2NgeeRGnI7G3z0aqqlJT/WPKDHEQoI8Jg8rA9EmcaDZqabRPY8BTiAaOOBpnCpgji7JpdvvVerPfNU35i/kqL9TZcVRaaru9vbt/qBVeeDm1Wzfw9abUiKL4P0N/2YGZrJh@yOO1KLrcySTBMdAlbzUPU5R6sLXKtsXc/6lvqa6zkhf8Ag)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 25 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
{∧/(9<≢⍵)(3≤+/⍵∊⎕D),⍵≢⌽⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRx3J9DUubR52LHvVu1dQwftS5RFsfyHzU0fWob6qLpg6IDZTs2Qtk1P5Pe9Q24VFvH1DK0/9RV/Oh9caP2iYCecFBzkAyxMMz@H@agnpAgLO7oZGxu3NAgDoXgg@ikPnpyQUFYL4BkGNiamZuYQnmhhQZlCaZpOQXqRmrcyGpB0sm5xcVpSaXKGTkFxWnKiQllpSkFlUqFJckFuSkIhluCLf8UUMzmE5MSgYKJyclQnhIACZtaQmSBQA)

Comment: Good. Now you can golf it by making it into a train: `(9<≢)∧(3≤1⊥∊∘⎕D)∧⊢≢⌽` and then save one more byte by rearranging to avoid parens: `(9<≢)∧≢∘⌽⍨∧3≤1⊥∊∘⎕D` Let em know if you need explanation of these steps.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 32 bytes

```perl6
{$_ ne.flip&&m:g/\d/>2&&.comb>9}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYy9CsMgAIR3n8KhOOa/aS3UJUNWh46FosakARNF7RBKn92akkBvuPs4jjPSqjpMC0Q9vMLwPjzgLJNejQah6TKk9y4lBUKJ0BMn@BPUOEtHSIL6aI4tgdKmzYuybSgFG6@x8yCMAVmE6lifzhjcbPbiVactKvcJENpaKTx8ausk5Mx7aRfoPDNKbqP89w8YF5EFZ4D9aa0xju0X)

Anonymous code block that simply enforces that all the rules are complied with.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{          &&         &&       }  # Anonymous code block
 $_ ne.flip                       # Input is not equal to its reverse
             m:g/\d/>2            # There are more than two digits
                        .comb>9   # There are more than 9 characters
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>117</s> 111 bytes

```
func[s][d: charset"0123456789"n: 0 parse s[any[d(n: n + 1)|
skip]]all[n > 2 9 < length? s s <> reverse copy s]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY49b8MgEEB3fsWJIUrVxU7SNnaiZIjUrFbVDTFgwHEUhNFBIlnqf3dhKo25gdO7r4daTV9aMU66euruVjLPmapB9gK9DrQoV@vN2/vHtqK2hgJcwuCZsCNTy4gsvEL58kP87eo4F8YwCwdYQQV7MNpeQn8EH2N/ANQPnabl4EbwnE8OrzZAB7RpTud46HxqGkqeafrm9CKdy2jm@Qe/sbi3GzXgYk0J2X0K48d6tikbkAOilgH6IXm2IgSNUTUIZ/RMoXzSzVLRyliXrchZ9v63VlXqnH4B)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5 `-p`, 33 bytes

```
$_=/.{10}/&y/0-9//>2&reverse ne$_
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##TYw9C8IwFEX3/IoOpVtN0g81gy4dumZwL0l8aKE04SUKRfzrxlZa8C73cLhcBzjUMabdie5enL1pNlGWC0rPRYbwBPSQjJB2MUrZtLwo20ZKsvJSG9@Mc4TNUNX7w1GQC7KHrq4Ws3KbEGMRwYTkbpdbrUIAnBIflBtgHfHfP1HazGy0IuovixZith/rQm9HH3M3fAE)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>31</s> 28 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to ngn!

```
{(x~|x)<(2<#x^x^/$!10)*9<#x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWqOirqZC00bDyEa5Iq4iTl9F0dBAU8sSyKv9n6auoRQQ4OxuaGScnlxQoGQN44EoIM8AyDQxNTO3sARyQooMSpNMUvKL1IwRCqHaCCsEspLzi4pSk0sUMvKLilMVkhJLSlKLKhWKSxILclKVNB81NP8HAA)

Comment: you could use `+//` (sum until convergence) instead of `+/+/` (sum sum)

Comment: alternatively, you could use `x^x^y` to find the intersection between two lists: `#x^x^,/!10`. this can be shortened to `#x^x^/!10` (`^` is "without", `x^/`... is `^`-reduction with initial value `x`)

Comment: one more thing, `>` (or `<`) can be used as "and not": `{(x~|x)<(2<#x^x^/$!10)*9<#x}`

Comment: @ngn Thank you! Nice way to find the intersection!

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 66 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$s=s<>reverse s&&s%(0,8)<s&&sum[1\\c<-s|isDigit c]>2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBNa4NAEIbP@iv2kPoBCWiSthE0l6QNhR6E5GakjOvWCKsrO2tCoL@9VgMm2r3M7sMz@w5DOYOyKURac0YKyMsmLyohFdmr9K086xMM0F9LdmYSGUHDwCfLma5sv7vWReQej9Sf4U@O2zzLFaHxet7sFbQ/BAQ4J5YVBPZB1swmVgEVmZBMiPSrAsSLkCnaxDAe4jtwfJgJDEX9cmKS6dq4v42JIjMMNzt3vthtwtCMp7qm3VFX/qGMVlWPnPa9fH55XXk9OUinTpapkMbCjGNdGw0xSus7qJCSUUVOottRAkoxeSWooOJsHO0OB4SEtoQmcAeDM5A87@bEzS/95pBhM/v4bLbXEoqc4h8)

- `s<>reverse s`: `s` is not a palindrome
- `s%%(0,8)<s`: the first 9 characters of `s` are less than all of `s`
- `sum[1\\c<-s|isDigit c]>2`: `s` has more than two digits

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 40 bytes

```
G`.{10}
G`(\d.*){3}
+`^(.)(.*)\1$
$2
^..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYw9C4MwGIT391c42BJbCEbth7ND1gwdRfJhsIVS5TUdivjb01gUess9dxyH1j1eyu8Il55LOrF0Bi5J3dJDMuUzHGVDaEJCqlkMcQYNpd4LUXGW5bwSAlZebOPODAOkAYrT@XIt4YbpWxdtj/t8m4DpEa1x0b3H0UZaOWfxE41ODU@7jtjvH5Q2gY1WoP601GUZ2i8) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
G`.{10}
```

Checks for at least 10 characters.

```
G`(\d.*){3}
```

Checks for at least 3 digits.

```
+`^(.)(.*)\1$
$2
```

Remove the first and last character if they match.

```
^..
```

If there are at least 2 characters then it wasn't a palindrome.

.NET's balancing groups mean that this can be done in a single regular expression, but that takes 47 bytes:

```
^(?!(.)*.?(?<-1>\1)*$(?(1).))(?=.{10})(.*\d){3}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYw9C8IwFEX3/IoKKi8FQ2PrR0HN0KFrBsciJmlQQWx5jYOU/vbYSgve5R4Ol4vWPV7KLyC/@guIGTAaMgHisOKngtNwDgI4ZZSCOLKWRx0FFhYlbePOeymznK/jPJOSjDzUxDdT1yTqIdlsd/uUnDF666SscBlPE2IqRGtccK@wsYFWzln8BI1T9dOOI/77J0qbno1WRP1l0Gna2y8) Link includes test cases.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>74</s> <s>72</s> 64 bytes

Thanks [Neil A.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69401/neil-a) for -2 bytes!
Thanks [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king) for -8 bytes!

```python
lambda s:s[9:]and re.findall('\d',s)[2:]and s[::-1]!=s
import re
```

Explanation:

```python
lambda s: # Create lambda                                          
           s[9:] # Check if the string is at least 10 characters long                                 
                     and re.findall('\d',s)[2:] #Check for at least 3 matches of the regex \d (which matches all digits)
                     and s[::-1] != s # Check if the string reversed is equal to the string (palindrome test)
import re  # Import regex module
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVHLboMwEDzDV2yJ1IBEo7z6AIlDlLZRpR6Q0hvJwYADlsC2bKdNVPXbqSEooSrqqXuxxzs7s7vmR5UzOqsEBLCpClTGKQLpy8jzt4imIPBoR2iKisIebtKhK51oesrIyPdvJturQJqk5Ewoza0SJgROVBCZhhWGy9VkOlstw9ByL7g@ujhLOG/wWIP57d39g9fANzHex/OUieuZZW5NQnu0LdeoY2ArxkDmuglHJ1siaCwxxEgpLI4gFeIFbioGNmUKMGX7LIeUZERJ5yw6OTXcCnNU6PEFK3HNaJ@7hlDvolcOxYlWS2L0u8um6Kc06kSP@582nle7tDX4XU@rckIz@BCMZo5e3o4JOACh0K7GNw2yA2EfHH0zuCBU2Va4WK@fHuHzyxppfomUTmsDXEjcYT0vXl57WMbF4/xTJ5e66f9zqr4B)

Comment: [-2 bytes by shifting the parentheses around](https://tio.run/##rVHLTsMwEDwnX7GkEk2kUvXFI4EeqgIVEodI5VZ6cBI3seTYlu1Cq4pvD04atUFEnPDFO97Zmd212OuMs3FRkFxwqUHiezmlKI8SBCrwHyhmrvIQS2BUxRL3N4QliFK3@550e8qrkmoVBFfD9cVUFTGXEsd6urItJwzni@FovJiHodM74/Jq4jQWosIDAybXN7d3fgXf5GAbTRIuL8eOvbYJa9F2elZ5Oq7mHFRmZvBMsiaCwQpDhLTGcg9KI0FxVdFxGdeAGd@mGSQkJVp5J9HhseFaWCBqJpY8xyWjfm4aQrmBVjkUxUYtjtDvLquin9KocVrc/7Tx/dKlrsEfZlqdEZbCp@Qs9czyNlzCDgiDejWBbZENSHfnmcgSkjDtOuFsuXx6hMOX0zf8HGmTNgaYKtxgPc9eXltY1tnj9FNHl7Lp/3MqvgE)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 70 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.length>9&(a.match(/\d/g)||[]).length>2&a!=[...a].reverse().join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/LboMwEEXX5SumKIpsqXGefaAINiyyZdEdQWIwBhJRjGwXqSJ8O4UqNMxm5sy90sy9YoOaq0ttVpVMRZ@5PboeslJUuSk8Z0mQfaHhBVmf03VOb7cwopO6W@KzGzLGMGJKNEJpQSi7yksVx32DCozQxkctNLgQ2kHgn7a7/ckPAvsFJhzbDHNe1yNuhvnw@vb@4Yz0qTbfySGVarkfceYfRy6VEtxAIYcPIEFjhPoBbbAuxcO6nQ5jwgfiCf7BrO6i49w1sKOjZWVSASmF@U8DMnsko9BaT1xWWpaClTInsb1oJ7WzYeXBos3ItKFdTI9W1/8C)

Returns 1 for true and 0 for false

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 67 bytes

```cs
n=>n.Count(char.IsDigit)>2&!n.Reverse().SequenceEqual(n)&n.Length>9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5dS8MwGIXv8ytiLkoCNbTb/KhzRag6hF0UJ3jjTRrftoHypkvSgYz99trJBp6b83A4HI7219qb8XVA/eiDM9jElbVdXq9GXOUoCztg4LpVTr75Z9OYIPJZdIXyHfbgPHAht7AbADW87AbVcRQRyg1gE9o8G5ektg6UbvleOWqoQfrEyrJYp7P5uihLcuaTXbjRfU@SCRY3t3f3GflwyVAtvq2L5pcK0dY50IG2dvpAKxUCuB/qg@o7OJfSv31V6Ql1pYj6p1OcZVPK5LbvTODsC5kQ5NOZABuDwNkhOT7QQ3pksYlrboRYjr8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 19 bytes

```
#a>9&XD Na>2&aNERVa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@B@vV6xX/V850c5SLcJFwS/Rzkgt0c81KCzxf62Cr0I0l4JSQICzu6GRsbtzQIASgguikLjpyQUFIK4BkG1iamZuYQnihRQZlCaZpOQXqRkjqQUxk/OLilKTSxQy8ouKUxWSEktKUosqFYpLEgtyUhFKDWGWgnBiUjJQJDkpEcxBAlBJS0uwXOz//7p5/6FWAQA) (all test cases)

#### Explanation

With `a` being the first command-line argument:

```
#a > 9      Length of a is greater than 9
&           and
XD N a > 2  Number of matches of regex [0-9] iN a is greater than 2
&           and
a NE RV a   a is not (string-)equal to reverse of a
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ûc╖»¬ë⌂╓âó╗cCé
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9663b7afaa897fd683a2bb634382&i=%22PPCG123GCPP%22%0A%22PPCG123PPCG%22%0A%22PPCG123gcpp%22%0A%220123456789%22%0A%22Tr0ub4dor%263%22%0A%22PPCG123%22%0A%22correct+horse+battery+staple%22%0A%22PPCG121GCPP%22%0A%22%22%0A%22abc121cba%22%0A%22aaaaaaaaaaaa%22%0A%22abc99cba%22&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 17 bytes

```
&&<2l@`MTQ<9lQ!_I
```

Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%26%26%3C2l%40%60MTQ%3C9lQ%21_I&input=%22Tr0ub4dor%263%22&debug=0), or verify all the test cases at once [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%26%26%3C2l%40%60MTQ%3C9lQ%21_I&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22PPCG123GCPP%22%0A%22PPCG123PPCG%22%0A%22PPCG123gcpp%22%0A%220123456789%22%0A%22Tr0ub4dor%263%22%0A%22PPCG123%22%0A%22correct%20horse%20battery%20staple%22%0A%22PPCG121GCPP%22%0A%22%22%0A%22abc121cba%22%0A%22aaaaaaaaaaaa%22%0A%22abc99cba%22&debug=0).

```
&&<2l@`MTQ<9lQ!_IQ   Implicit: Q=eval(input()), T=10
                     Trailing Q inferred
      `MT            [0-10), as strings
     @   Q           Take characters from input which are in the above
    l                Length
  <2                 Is the above greater than 2?
            lQ       Length of Q
          <9         Is the above greater than 9?
               _IQ   Is Q unchanged after reversal?
              !      Logical NOT
&&                   Logical AND the three results together
```

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, (47 bytes)

```
{p->p=~/.{10}/&&p=~/(\d.*){3}/&&p!=p.reverse()}
```

(Bonus inclusion is left as an exercise to the reader)