# Passwords Strong Against Bishops

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, path-finding, chess

Not to be confused with [Password Bishop Goodness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/179841/password-bishop-goodness)!

Given a string, answer (truthy/falsy or two consistent values) if it constitutes a password which is *strong against bishops*.

A password is *strong against bishops* if it is a string consisting of alternating letters (in `a-h`) and digits (in `1-8`) such that each pair of characters can be interpreted as a square on a chessboard, and if you place a white pawn on each square named in the password, then there is no way for a white bishop to travel, in any number of consecutive moves, from any square in the first (`1`) row to any square in the last (`8`) row.

### Examples

#### Passwords strong against bishops

- `a1b1c1d1e1f1g1h1`
- `a8b8c8d8e8f8g8h8`
- `a1b2c3d4d5f5f4g3g4h2b5`
- `h4g4f4e4c4b4a4c3e3`
- `a1b1c1d1e1f1g1a8b8c8d8e8f8g8`
- `b4b5d4d5f4f5g3h5`

> For example, `a1b1c1d1e1f1g1a8b8c8d8e8f8g8` corresponds to the position [image: foo] and `b4b5d4d5f4f5g3h5` corresponds to the position [image: foo]

#### Passwords weak against bishops

- `a4c4e4g4g5d6f6e3d2b2` (well-formed but not strong — thanks Jo King for this example!)
- `b1c1d1e1f1g1h1a8b8c8d8e8f8g8` (well-formed but not strong)
- `h4g4f4e4c4b4a4c3` (well-formed but not strong)
- `d4` (well-formed but not strong)
- `b4b5d4d5f4f5g2h5` (well-formed but not strong)
- `correct horse battery staple` (ill-formed)
- `1a1b1c1d1e1f1g8a8b8c8d8e8f8g` (ill-formed)
- `a` (ill-formed)
- `aa` (ill-formed)

Comment: What color squares does the bishop go on?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance `from any square in the first (1) row to any square in the last (8) row.` The bishop tries a path from all squares in the first row. Question: is `1a` equal to `a1` for being parsed as a chess square?

Comment: Can the bishop take pawns? Can opposing pawns take the bishop?

Comment: Your 2nd last test case contradicts your spec. You also need to explain **how** "*each pair of characters can be interpreted as a square on a chessboard*".

Comment: a1b2c3d4d5f5f4g3g4h2b5 is not strong against bishops, since a bishop can get to h5, then go down to d1

Comment: suggested case: `a` and `aa`

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance: "a1b2c3d4d5f5f4g3g4h2b5 is not strong against bishops..." — No, the direct route from d1 to h5 is blocked by the pawn on g4. (I used chessboardjs.com to view the non-trivial examples.)

Comment: @TRITICIMAGVS, Ourous: I've clarified that both the pawns and the bishop are white, so neither is allowed to capture (or land on, or move through, or jump over) the other.

Comment: @Shaggy: When you posted that comment, the "2nd last test case" was `correct horse battery staple`, which is *obviously* not strong against bishops according to the spec as I read it. Can you perhaps clarify what you meant by "Your 2nd last test case contradicts your spec"? (Assuming it still matters, that is.)

Comment: @Veskah: The ill-formed/weak example `1a2a3a4a5a6a7a1h2h3h4h5h6h7h` already answers your question as to whether `1a` is an acceptable variation of `a1`. (It's not.)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread the spec - I read it as we would be **given** "*a string consisting of alternating letters (in `a-h`) and digits (in `1-8`) such that each pair of characters can be interpreted as a square on a chessboard*" - i.e, we were guaranteed the input would match the RegEx `[a-h][1-8]+`.

Comment: This is still in need of an explanation of *how* each pair of characters corresponds to a square on a chessboard as well as a worked example or 2.

Comment: @Arnauld: Oops! I blame my instinctive zero-indexing. That `g2` should have been `g3`. Fixed now. @Shaggy: I think you'll just have to look at http://chessboardjs.com or the Wikipedia page for [chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess#Setup) or something. A full description of how "d4" corresponds to a square, or how a bishop moves, or whether a white piece can capture another white piece, is supposed to be out-of-scope for this specific puzzle.

Comment: Can the input contain capital letters, and if yes, do `[A-H]` also count? Or can we assume the input always consist of `[a-z0-9 ]` (based on the test cases given)?

Comment: Also, could you add an example for one of the truthy test cases. Because I understand that the squares of the password are filled with white pawns, but I don't understand where the white bishop is placed. And if any place is fine, why can't it travel to each row `1` through `8` in the first test case? It cannot travel to each column, since the `a` column is completely filled with pawns, but it can travel to each row without a problem, can it not? I have the feeling I'm missing something.. :S

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Yikes. For `a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8`, read `a1b1c1d1e1f1g1h1`! I don't blame you for being confused, now that I see that! Does that clarify? Also I'll look into adding some inline chess grids. As for `[A-H]`, I'd say strictly speaking the puzzle says not to count them as letters.

Comment: Suggested test case `b1d1f1h1g5d6f6e3d2b2c5 => false`. It seems most answers fail, since the bishop is forced to go backwards to make it to the end

Comment: @Quuxplusone Ah, now it indeed makes a lot more sense. xD

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby, <s>115</s> <s>182</s> 163 bytes

```ruby
->s{z=('00'..'99').map{|x|x=~/[09]/||s[(x[1].ord+48).chr+x[0]]};(11..18).map &g=->x{z[x]||[x-11,x-9,x+z[x]=9,x+11].map(&g)};s=~/^([a-h][1-8])*$/&&(z[81,9]-[9])[8]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZHdbqMwEIXv/RRWuwqwCU4GTGVU0RexvJL/HakNCKhEA/TVs6Z3dK5mjuZ8Z6TpP9XXwzWP/G2Y702aXC4JIUldJxn5kN28TMvUfJ/5pRbnZRl4OnEQpO3NkbKM6NAfJ34RYn1NAQgB9uPCB9/kb9N855NYFj7lAKcpr0/TcVOarYFIiZvpwWfr6xAT/qVc5kFwyJnI/v45Hw7pnTM41SLntcg4E@sjkaBAgwELDjwEQJIppplhljnmWWAobhS6NNRUrnLUl56GQlUoUE8dtVRTRSXVpS3RnrUHIUVV9QOhrvJlqFA0RbunvjIv7sWWplAF2h/zC/E7Ehm6xxYRq9u@t3rEoe0Hi5UcR9t/4WGU3btFsDuR7fhIIikT8n692YFYqQM2LV62cUE4VtdfbyN@ep4d38T4qfajE@R6G7qYt@LneZPXJ2Rv5vEf)

Returns `1` for strong and `nil` for weak. (The +67 bytes was for taking into account "backtracking.")

```ruby
->s{
 z=                             # this is the board
 ('00'..'99').map{|x|           # coordinates are described as y*10 + x
  x=~/[09]/||                   # truthy if out of bounds...
  s[(x[1].ord+48).chr+x[0]]     # ...or impassable
 }                              # now only the passable squares are falsey
 (11..18).map                   # for each x position at y=1,
  &g=->x{                       # call helper function on that square
   z[x]||                       # if the square is passable (i.e. falsey),
    [x-11,x-9,x+z[x]=9,x+11]    # mark it impassable by setting to 9 (truthy)
     .map(&g)                   # call helper recursively for each neighbor
  }
 s=~/^([a-h][1-8])*$/           # make sure the input was valid,
 &&(z[81,9]-[9])[8]             # and check that the last row was never reached
}
```

A few tricks that were used:

- Instead of the numerical range `0..99`, we use the *string* range `'00'..'99'` so that the number is automatically left-padded to 2 digits and stringified. This makes out of bounds checking very short -- match with regex `/[09]/`.
- Inside the helper function, while building the list of new coordinates `[x-11, x-9, x+9, x+11]`, we simultaneously assign `z[x]` to `9` in the process, which happens to be a truthy value (marking the square visited).
- In the last line, we want to check that the array `z[81,9]` does not contain `9`. We do this by removing all instances of `9` (`z[81,9]-[9]`), then asking for the 9th element of the resulting array (`[8]`). Since we know the array originally had 9 elements, if any were removed, we'll get `nil`, whereas if they all remained, we'll get the last element of the array (which happens to always be `1`).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>330</strike> <strike>318</strike> <strike>313</strike> <strike>309</strike> 370 bytes

```
import numpy as n
b=n.ones([8,8])
q=r=1
s=input()
l=len(s)
def g(x,y=0,p=0):
    if b[y,x]and p<32:
        if y<7:
            if x<7:
                g(x+1,y+1,p+1)
                if y:g(x+1,y-1,p+1)
            if x:
                g(x-1,y+1,p+1)
                if y:g(x-1,y-1,p+1)
        else:global q;q=0
for i in range(l/2):
    x=ord(s[2*i])-97;y=ord(s[2*i+1])-49
    if y>8or y<0 or l%2or x>8or x<0:r=0
    if r:b[7-y,x]=0
map(g,range(8))
print q&r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHfbpswFMav66ewInWBBTZsTOPSeC8S5cLGf0Aihhiq4qfPbFqto9MuDEe/c77vO4bRz@1g8b0ZpIIM7na7e3cdBzdD@3odPeQTtEAw@2OwakrONKOXFNyYYwhMrLPj65ykoGe9ssmUAqk0NMmSeVZkIyvSGjx0Goqzz5YLtxKOpxIHFqE/HWMVy@WjfAjSA8p8OOMBpSuKk/UHzz95VP3R5P/R5BuN6idVm34QvIe3lxsrgB4c7GBnoePWqKT/iePCCxucTKYz/t5d0vz5@OI/wQEFRJ7XW/lfNOj9qYDh1T/i8FxWtJyK2gX7OORqcT7m8foBXPmYmOw9jKYpGF1nZ3j75u7hswPw1na9gqhWi2pg/B/3PUcCNUgihTQyqEV7sOdU0IZKqqimhrY0IiRwU0oiK11pYkpDWiyq0GiJIZoo0hBBOGlKVb5P/@W5tQttQUS1WhFdmbKNNkEaTAwxlXzST6qUWOA4uVntH6Ov4QFJ8jUArwHN4JxqZtgOblJQ8HlWzsNp5mOvQhttVqabpLhePHz/Gw)

[Try practical version online!](https://tio.run/##dZHfbpswFMav66ewInWBBTYMpnFpvBeJcmHjPyAR4xiq4qfPbFqto9MuDEe/c77vOwbr52405b0dhYQU7na7e3@1o5uheb1aD9kEDeDU/BiNnJIzycglBTfqKAIT7Y19nZMUDHSQJplSIKSCOlkyT4vM0iJtwEOvID/7bLkwI6A9oSKwCP3pGKtYLh/lQ5AeUObDsQeUrihONh88/@RR9UeT/0eTbzRymGSjh5GzAd5ebrQAanSwh72Bjhktk@FnGRde6OhEMp3L7/0lzZ@PL/4THFBA@Hm9lf9Fgt6fChhew2MZnsuKllPRuGAfh1zDz8c8Xj@AK7OJzt7DSJoC63ozw9s3dw@fHYC3rh8kRI1cZAvj/7jvGeKoRQJJpJBGHdqDPSOctEQQSRTRpCMRIV62lcCiVrXCutK4K3kdGh3WWGGJW8wxw20lq/fpvzy3dqHNMa9XK6xqXXXRJkiDica6Fk/qSVai5GWc3Kz2j9HX8IAE/hpQrgHt6JxsZ9iNbpKQs3mWzsNpZnaQoY02K5NNUlwvHrb/DQ) (original can take 4^32 operations to check completely, I suggest using this one - same number of bytes)

Not a super short solution - I couldn't figure out how to make a lambda function version of g shorter than g itself.

-4 bytes thanks to Quuxplusone

+61 bytes accounting for backtracking (thanks for pointing that out Jo King and for the golfing tips)

Comment: Nice. `q=r=1` would be shorter than `q=1 r=1`, right? And `if r:` shorter than `if r>0:`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>490</s> <s>476</s> 474

```
def f(p):
 a=[set(ord(c)-33 for c in s)for s in"* )+ *, +- ,. -/ .0 / \"2 !#13 \"$24 #%35 $&46 %'57 &(68 '7 *: )+9; *,:< +-;= ,.<> -/=? .0>@ /? 2B 13AC 24BD 35CE 46DF 57EG 68FH 7G :J 9;IK :<JL ;=KM <>LN =?MO >@NP ?O BR ACQS BDRT CESU DFTV EGUW FHVX GW JZ IKY[ JLZ\\ KM[] LN\\^ MO]_ NP^` O_ R QS RT SU TV UW VX W".split()];x=set((ord(p[i+1])-49)*8+ord(p[i])-97 for i in range(0,len(p),2))
 r=set(range(8))-x
 for i in range(99):r=set().union(*[a[c]for c in r])-x
 return all(c<56 for c in r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHZUqNAFH33K864Adm0oSGEbJpVszquMxJUlgZSpkgKsEq/PtPGsQxW@da37tnu6dVbGi4jeb32mA9fXEnGDl7rCUvFZeyJK3NuSUWqV/J67v@cJ5bkL2PMMY8Q21HAxOPCgkWcWpAlqRpvyB8LXZKKrzv4hJvEylUqxgdCKr1E82Uk5kzz0@1ZKirKBv38Lp5sfBL@3M1ByiNXQL6IQgnFI5SOcYTZroxfe0Thj32ZYu9AUbF/SDUcCGoZh6KmQygjZ3BypcrpRo0LVOtcotbgIvUml2mc4KgJuQWinLYh01YHitrugmqdHtRytw9N752h3IcxQKV6PoRRG4xQrQ/HqDVGE9Sb4ykaJ5MLNKdoXeK0/fsKrc7lNdrdqxt0ete36PZv7tA7u/2D/h0G9zgf/jUxGN3PZhiOTQujyWz2gPHUesTk4uEJ00dcgstwES7BBTidk@92S8lqMefdWaZrvZfjbj7B2rQcs/QljmAvFqJbUzV87aX1Kp5HKYTr@IUlhrDzMfqiYBOHuMQjjPgkICERpK2d7uiu7ulM9/VAD/XMjjiyq3jUU33Vp4ES0FB21G1ESAPqU0Zd6lCbugpTvvG3fLNO2ziHOurGhfpqoIRfDkLPXiTZWxyu5/MbAtXTfI0pnswzZjJlb/3Z9Xv27Z1Hf8wnhxk3dxnHzE0RLuOEwbHTlMVvSFJ7tWDbOJIpQ8/EynSWGfi0/gc)

This works by "flood-fill." First we create a list `a` of which squares are adjacent to which other squares, bishopwise. Then we create a set `x` of exclusions (based on the password). Then we initialize a set `r` of reachable squares, which starts out as just the first row (minus any exclusions), and repeatedly "flood" outward from there, 99 times, which should be more than enough. Finally, we test to see if any of the squares in the last row ended up in our reachable set. If so, we have a weak password! If not, we have a strong password.

Disadvantage, perhaps disqualifying (I don't know the usual rule here): If the password is ill-formed (such as "correct horse battery staple"), then we throw an exception instead of returning `False`. But we do always return `True` iff the password is strong!

Minus 16 bytes thanks to Jo King. We inline `a` in the one place it's used, and constant-fold some math.

```
def f(p):
 x=set(ord(p[i])-489+8*ord(p[i+1])for i in range(0,len(p),2));r=set(range(8))-x
 for i in[1]*99:r=set().union(*[[set(ord(k)-33for k in s)for s in"* )+ *, +- ,. -/ .0 / \"2 !#13 \"$24 #%35 $&46 %'57 &(68 '7 *: )+9; *,:< +-;= ,.<> -/=? .0>@ /? 2B 13AC 24BD 35CE 46DF 57EG 68FH 7G :J 9;IK :<JL ;=KM <>LN =?MO >@NP ?O BR ACQS BDRT CESU DFTV EGUW FHVX GW JZ IKY[ JLZ\\ KM[] LN\\^ MO]_ NP^` O_ R QS RT SU TV UW VX W".split()][c]for c in r])-x
 return all(c<56for c in r)
```

Comment: @JoKing thanks! There's still whitespace before two `for`s that I couldn't see how to remove. I found that replacing `range(99)` with `repr(f)` works on my local machine but not on tio.run's interpreter... but then I found that `[1]*99` was shorter anyway! So that saved 4 more bytes.

Comment: _whitespace before two `for`s that I couldn't see how to remove_ — Oh! Apparently Python treats `33for` as two tokens (whereas `for33` would be one token). Today I learned. Minus 2 more bytes, then.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>339</s> <s>316</s> <s>358</s> <s>353</s> 345 bytes

-23 bytes thanks to @Doorknob.

+42 bytes accounting for backtracking.

```
p[m_]:=StringPartition[#,m]&;l=Range@8;f[n_]:=Check[w=(8#2+#1-8)&@@@({LetterNumber@#,FromDigits@#2}&@@@(p@1/@p[UpTo@2]@n));g=Graph[Sort/@UndirectedEdge@@@Position[Outer[EuclideanDistance@##&,#,#,1],N@Sqrt@2]&@GraphEmbedding@GridGraph@{8,8}//Union]~VertexDelete~w;c:=#~Complement~w&;m=0;Do[m+=Length@FindPath[g,i,j],{i,c@l},{j,c[l+56]}];m==0,0>1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLRatswFH3vV5gYspa6pHLkIho8BE07tpUuW9btwZghS9eyWltyZYVshOTXMyXbWFxa9KSrc8@59@g0zFXQMKc4227brPmRX6ZzZ5WWM2adcsroLIyafDip0y9MS6BkUmZ6B7uqgD9my/SYhPFpiM7IyZBSery6BefA3i2aAiwNoxtrmqmSynU0jNd7SEvRiLbZffvV0Din@uRkItN3lrVVNjfWjei9FsoCdyCuhZekdGa6P7N8Wnju7HrBayWA6anqHNMcaBgOo9AflEd3dP5knSce0j3ntR9ECL@RvyqxL9EVich6NLrXnjPffAPr4OcUanCwWU74ZRpurkzT1tCAdpvlcNKk55OpyZrT9Ba0dBW9UVrMvHeZjFT0kEcrFXFar6PVQ8Sz@jS5yNe570rPo/O3KN8ezbylLht4a42Wl4P8b6GkA4YKxJFAgEokUYV6b6QgnAgCpCSSVORZX8zHAoukTEosxxJXcZEcIioscYkBc1xghvkYxq/r9pUOcQUukr0KLhM5rnYK/7b5Duyxt0t/k9c5n092@Cbwq@pxT/2DCT76X33TBV0LXLE6WPp5gs7Ui11U@iZ7KfCiMhEX5QWMRVzEB1Tv6/rsxtgGRK@LG7tLYVAZ20FQsF2ufwU@cT4Zg3w0@rxQ4P7DUc9S0ls/eAHPXqodFI@2vwE)

I rewrote most of this to account for backtracking, I think there may be an easier way to define the graph `g`, Mathematica has `GraphData[{"bishop",{8,8}}]` which is the graph of all moves a bishop can make on a chessboard ([Bishop Graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BishopGraph.html)), but this graph includes connections further than nearest diagonal neighbor. If anyone knows a shorter way to do that let me know. Credit for the graph construction goes to [this MathematicaSE answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110850/53487).

Returns `True` for strong passwords, `False` for weak/ill-formed passwords. Note that for most of the ill-formed passwords it will produce a bunch of error messages and then return `False`. If this is not in line with the rules then they can be suppressed by changing `f[n_]:=...` to `f[n_]:=Quiet@...` costing 6 bytes.

Ungolfed:

```
p[m_] := StringPartition[#, m] &;

f[n_] :=
 Check[
  w = (8 #2 + #1 - 
       8) & @@@ ({LetterNumber@#, FromDigits@#2} & @@@ (p@1 /@ 
        p[UpTo@2]@n));
  r = GridGraph[{8, 8}];
  g = Graph[Sort /@ UndirectedEdge @@@
             Position[Outer[EuclideanDistance@## &, #, #, 1],N@Sqrt@2] &@
              GraphEmbedding@r // Union]~VertexDelete~w;
  s = Complement[{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},w];
  e = Complement[{57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64},w];
  m = 0;
  Do[m += Length@FindPath[g, i, j], {i, s}, {j, e}];
  If[m == 0,True,False]
  , False]
```

Breakdown:

```
p[m_]:=StringPartition[#,m]&
```

Takes a string argument and splits it into a list of strings each of length `m`.

```
Check[...,False]
```

Returns `False` if any error messages are produced, which is how we catch the ill-formed strings (i.e. assume they are well-formed, inevitably producing an error down the line).

```
(8*#2 + #1 - 8) & @@@ ({LetterNumber@#, FromDigits@#2} & @@@ (p@1 /@ 
        p[UpTo@2]@n));
```

Takes the string of pawn positions and splits it such that `"a2h5b"` becomes `{{"a","2"},{"h","5"},{"b"}}`, then `LetterNumber` will convert the letter to a number (`a -> 1`, etc) and `FromDigits` converts the numeral into an integer. If the string is not well formed, this step will produce an error which will be caught by `Check`, returning `False`. These two numbers are then converted to an integer corresponding to a square on the board.

```
r = GridGraph[{8, 8}];
g = Graph[
     Sort /@ UndirectedEdge @@@ 
          Position[Outer[EuclideanDistance@## &, #, #, 1], 
           N@Sqrt@2] &@GraphEmbedding@r // Union]~VertexDelete~w;
```

Constructs the graph of all nearest-neighbor diagonal edges with the pawn positions deleted.

```
s = Complement[{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},w];
e = Complement[{57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64},w];
```

These are lists of unoccupied starting and ending vertices respectively

```
m=0
Do[m += Length@FindPath[g, i, j], {i, s}, {j, e}];
If[m == 0,True,False]
```

Loops over the starting and ending vertices, for each pair `FindPath` will be a list of paths between them. If there are no paths between them, it will be an empty list, so `Length@` returns `0`. If there are no paths at all, then `m` will be zero, and we return `True`, otherwise return `False`.

Comment: A few tips: `True` and `False` can be `1>0` and `0>1` respectively. `p[1]@#&/@` is equivalent to just `p@1/@`. `Sequence@@` can be replaced with `##&@@`. Instead of `{LetterNumber[#[[1]]],FromDigits[#[[2]]]}&/@`, you can use `{LetterNumber@#,FromDigits@#2}&@@@`.

Comment: @Doorknob thanks! Code golfing is teaching me all sorts of new things about Mathematica. I still don't 100% understand `p@1/@`, but I see the general idea. I suppose `p@1 = StringPartition[#,1]&`, it's slightly confusing to me I guess because `p` takes two arguments two different ways, one as `m_` and the other as `#...&`, I guess this is just a matter of precedence. It makes sense though that `p@m = p[m]`.

Comment: It has for me as well! The main change there is that for any function `f` that takes a single argument, `f@#&` has the same behavior as just `f` -- here, `f` is `p[1]`. (Then I changed the `[]` notation to `@`, which is always identical except for precedence.)

Comment: @JoKing that's devious, this is more complicated than I first thought, having to consider backwards movements as well. Thanks

Comment: @JoKing wrote a new one which accounts for backtracking.

Comment: Does `TransitiveReductionGraph[GraphData["bishop",{8,8}]] ` work?

Comment: @PeterTaylor wow great find, I'll mess with it, looks like it should work

Comment: @PeterTaylor so the `TransitiveReductionGraph` doesn't give exactly what I need, as it reduces the graph to the minimal number of edges necessary to reach any position, whereas I was to keep all edges connecting nearest diagonal neighbors. I'll think about it more, I'm sure there's a way to do it with the bishop graph.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 285 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Data.List
$_[_]=1<0
$a[x,y:l]=case[[u,v]\\u<-[0..7],v<-[0..7]|u==toInt x-97&&v==toInt y-49]of[p]= $[p:a]l;_=1<0
$a _=all(\[_,y]=y<7)(iter 64(nub o\e=e++[k\\[u,v]<-e,p<-[-1,1],q<-[-1,1],k<-[[abs(u+p),abs(v+q)]]|all((<>)k)a&&all((>)8)k])(difference[[e,0]\\e<-[0..7]]a))
```

```
$[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZBNb4JAFEX3/goWBpkwGCaxpVrGlV2YuGjicnghTxgsYfgQBiKJv71TtLW7czf3vvMSJbEyZZ32Slol5pXJy6ZutXXU6Uc10B1qXB7yTs/msYiBs9CfzVFc6bhRwBPspBA9HSCK@tAT/nIZAB2edOs51/W@0tbVWwe2PTzj6K3WUGeiAW7NRbNBUO/xX7cVc1TKiURMR@BjGBAn17K1XldO1Z@sOpJcuq4oougxHHqSNtOgxygDevmnYiKBp87p3YbQOwzuhQDc7uVOuCUFQdt@hC15IwUQJ82zTLaySiYnSf3JST5NAAkxR43TY@4Xg1ggO7GEpUyyjJ3ZAsx3kik8d8bbH8xurLDMk9/wqVBndVsa78u8@H75Aw)

`$[]` is `$ :: [[Int]] [Char] -> Bool` composed with the first argument, giving `\ [Char] -> Bool`.

The function works by consuming the string two characters at a time, immediately returning false if the string is in an invalid format as soon as it sees the invalid part. Once the string has been processed, it places a bishop on every empty square on one side of the board and moves them in every way possible 64 times and checks if any of the end positions is in the target row.

Comment: Seems to incorrectly return `True` for `a1b1c1d1e1f1g1`? Not that I understand anything about how it works. :)

Comment: @Quuxplusone I had a brain-fart and thought white bishops only used white squares. I've also added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 192 bytes

```python
import re
s=p=input()
t={0,1}
while s!=t:s=t;t=t|{i for x in s for i in[x-9,x-7,x+7,x+9]if-9<i<72and-2<x%8-i%8<2and"%c%d"%(97+i%8,i/8)not in p}
print(max(s)<64and""==re.sub("[a-h][1-8]","",p))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLbjtsgEH3nK6ZIUWwtbouNE5Ka/kiUB262kRLbAlb1Ks23pzbbSs0uEmg4M5w5w8z0FvtxqPjkH3o0FgRgjB/uOo0@grcoiEm4YXqNWY6iuH0n9I5@9e5iIXwR8RhE/BFF/H1z0I4eZnADhGS6xTzNxYHMxZ7ML@s@nF1bHBrX7Es5mKJs5g0v3IY36xVv9GY5ssP@ZYGI@8bzYYwr33RHk3dDzK5yzkLe7NgajoXw9mt4VRk@yaI/n2jBz5hgTKY8fyxFIBRtiGGp6IS2kiqqqaGWtrSjPd2SBeOKa2645S3veM8TRlWpK8NM3dYt66qO9aWqV0/POtYyyzRTTDJd2epv/H@8z4yrXzFVJzbW1l3VJ6bl9cLTsa42u3ZnK1OqMsU@KfzM9VHBihn2KUv5nkWP3lsdoR99sKBkjNa/QYhyutjVT5@k86d0SWU65PaMEPrXT0g/ekSwrPeWOAJY/ARMwA5GYJwnn52tztZxInDDaXrwEbKLvCojj@Dye47Q4w8)